# Objective C autorelease at RUNTIME level

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, runtime, autorelease

This is not a duplicate of a thread in that link, because my question is related to RUNTIME calls, NOT how autoreleasepool{} block works or why it is needed. I was asking what is the call stack of RUNTIME functions that happens when you use autoreleasepool{} block. In the thread brought in the link it wasn't described

Recently I was asked a question

> "Explain how an autorelease pool works at the runtime level?"

I know that in ARC **retain** and **release** calls are inserted by ObjC runtime library compile time. However I wasn't able to find any appropriate ObjC runtime function that might do that call.
So my questions are:

Q1: What happens at runtime when you use autorelease pool?

Q2: What functions are invoked?

Q3: What are the ObjC runtime functions for **retain/release**?

Comment: and please remove your downvote

Comment: @Willeke please remove the inappropriate downvote for duplicate question

Comment: @Willeke, I am sorry probably the issue is that because I haven't mentioned that I have dug the internet from up till down and wasn't able to find any precise and complete answer. But anyway pleaaaase, don't say that this is a duplicate question. In your link the questioner wants to know why do we need autoreleasepool in ARC still. I know the answer to this question (btw the answer was not complete I have added some few comments). My question is HOW autorelease is implemented via ObjC runtime commands. Rob Napier answered to my question. And thanks for upvote again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An autorelease pool is just a data structure that records future releases. Without ARC, when you send `-autorelease` to an object, a note is made in the autorelease pool. When `[pool drain]` is eventually called (or equivalently, when the pool is deallocated), it will send one `-release` to each object for each `-autorelease` that was requested.

Without autorelease, MRC would be very inconvenient. Every object returned from a method call would have to be explicitly released. (The called method can't release it, or it would be destroyed before the calling method could access it.)

ARC's implementation of autorelease is much more complicated. Autorelease introduced various performance impacts. One problem is that an autoreleased object is commonly retained by the caller. This means that in MRC there is very often a "retain/autorelease/retain/defferred-release" dance that is unnecessary and could be replaced by just "retain." The compiler can sometimes detect these, but sometimes this can't be detected until runtime. So there are special ARC methods like `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue` and `objc_autoreleaseReturnValue` that inspect the stack at runtime and try to avoid unnecessary autoreleases.

The details are provided in the [ARC documentation for Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#runtime-support). See the "Runtime support" section.

As for retain/release, these are implemented by `objc_retain` and `objc_release`.

Comment: Rob, thanks for the answer it actually spread light on lot's of questions I was asking to myself. The information in the link is really helpful. However I still have a question: Suppose we have an autoreleasepool{} block and there are number of temporary variables, so according to your answer and runtime functions descriptions - autoreleasepool created by objc_autoreleasePoolPush(pool), then by objc_autorelease(id value) objects are added to that pool and everything gets released when obj_autoreleasePoolPop(pool) is called?

Comment: It depends on what the compiler can optimize away, but as a first approximation, yes. And "gets released" just means "their retain count is reduced by one." It doesn't mean they're destroyed. Just released. In ARC, it is generally better to think in terms of strong and weak references, and let the compiler do its job, than to think too hard about the individual operations. But if you want to see them, you can emit assembly from the compiler and see exactly what it does.

Comment: If it helps, you could think of an `NSAutoreleasePool` as simply an `NSMutableArray` that does not retain objects added to it, but releases them. There is a thread-global variable that holds weak references to an array of such pools, and whenever you create an `NSAutoreleasePool`, it calls `[gAutoreleasePools addObject: self]` to make itself the current pool. `-autorelease` could naively be implemented as `[gAutoreleasePools.lastObject addObject: foo]`.